# How to add a PhotonView by script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

I want to add a PhotonView script to my gameobject, I have tried with `this.gameObject.AddComponent();` , but when I use it, it throws null.
What Am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Why not add it to a prefab?

Answer (score 0):

You should be passing the component type when calling the method. take a look at [GameObject.AddComponent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html). passing as string to this method is now obsolete.

Hope it helps!